# Nested class is not defined in itself

Tags: python-2.7, nested-class

The following code successfully prints `OK`:

```
class B(object):
        def __init__(self):
            super(B, self).__init__()
            print 'OK'

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
       self.B()

    B = B

A()
```

but the following which should work just as same as above one raises `NameError: global name 'B' is not defined`

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
       self.B()

    class B(object):
        def __init__(self):
            super(B, self).__init__()
            print 'OK'
A()
```

why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`B` is available in the scope of `A` class - use `A.B`:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
       self.B()

    class B(object):
        def __init__(self):
            super(A.B, self).__init__()
            print 'OK'

A()
```

See documentation on [Python Scopes and Namespaces](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces).