# Python - inner class is not defined?

Tags: python, inner-classes

I have to do an unrolled linked list for one of my classes. I'm new to python, but not to programming, and for some reason I cannot get around this little problem!

I have a class Node that is to be the node object used within the unrolled linked list. The unrolled linked list class performs all the operations on the Node class.

```
class UnrolledLinkedList(object):

    """ INNER NODE CLASS """
    class Node(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.array = []
            self.next_node = None
    """ END NODE CLASS """

    def __init__(self, max_node_capacity=16):
        self.max_node_capacity = max_node_capacity
        self.head = Node()


    """ OTHER FUNCTIONS OF UNROLLEDLINKEDLIST CLASS """
```

The problem comes at the last line of the UnrolledLinkedList class' **init** function: "global name Node is not defined". I double checked my indentation and looked all over the internet for examples of something like this, but couldn't find any. Would someone mind explaining to me what's wrong?

Comment: Why have you nested the classes?

Comment: Look for the nice explanation of your problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341914/nested-class-is-not-defined-in-itself)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Methods *do not* include their class as a scope to be searched. If you want this to work then you will need to use either `UnrolledLinkedList.Node` or `self.Node` instead.

Answer (score 9):

The inner class `Node` is a member of the class `UnrolledLinkedList` and can only be accessed via `self`.

```
def __init__(self, max_node_capacity=16):
    self.max_node_capacity = max_node_capacity
    self.head = self.Node()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
self.head = self.Node()
```

and it works.

A class does not create its own name space. Using `self.Node()`, Python first searches all attributes of the instances. Since it does not find the name `Node` there, it it searches the class `UnrolledLinkedList` for `Node`.

Alternatively, you can use the class name directly:

```
UnrolledLinkedList.Node()
```

You can achieve the same without nesting the class `Node`:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.array = []
        self.next_node = None

class UnrolledLinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self, max_node_capacity=16):
        self.max_node_capacity = max_node_capacity
        self.head = Node()
```

Answer (score 0):

Qualify `Node()` with `self`:

```
class UnrolledLinkedList(object):
    class Node(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.array = []
            self.next_node = None

def __init__(self, max_node_capacity=16):
    self.max_node_capacity = max_node_capacity
    self.head = self.Node()
```

Python needs to qualify references to things. In this case, you could either say `UnrolledLinkedList.Node()` or `self.Node()`.